# Checking internet connection on WIFI hotspot

Tags: android, networking

I'd like to check if the device has a real connection to the Internet, even connected to an opened wifi hotspot which requires log in.
The classic code :

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() && netInfo.isAvailable(){
   //connection on
}
```

works fine to see the device connected, but not really Internet.

I use :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout((int)(1000 * TIMEOUT)); 
                urlConnection.connect();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200 && url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost())) {
       //I am supposed to be connected
    }
```

because when connected on a hotspot, we are usually redirected to a login page. Though, here on my test the httpUrlConnection isn't redirected and then urlConnection.getURL.getHost() is really "google.com".

What to do?

Comment: use `setFollowRedirects(false)` see the behavior  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)

Comment: if I do so, the hotspot won't redirect me and then I won't be able to see that I am not on the host I expected, right? then I guess it does not help.

Comment: Oh you are right. Before digging more try the requestRouteToHost  method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923253/can-you-explain-the-functionality-of-requestroutetohost-in-android

Comment: requestRouteToHost returns me true even if I can not log to Internet via the browser (for instance) ...

Answer (score 5):

Got from Android 4.0.1 android.net.wifi.WifiWatchdogStateMachine:

```
private boolean isConnected() {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.getInputStream();
            return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 204;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Walled garden check - probably not a portal: exception " + e);
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
}
```